# Don't insert CLOSED line when node becomes DONE in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I want exactly the opposite to this: [No "CLOSED" line in org-mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34723/no-closed-line-in-org-mode)

Namely, I want emacs to stop inserting those annoying CLOSED lines in DONE nodes. Preferably on a per-file basis.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it myself, in the doc text for the `org-log-done` variable:

```
Possible values are:

nil     Don’t add anything, just change the keyword
time    Add a time stamp to the task
note    Prompt for a note and add it with template ‘org-log-note-headings’

This option can also be set with on a per-file-basis with

   #+STARTUP: nologdone
   #+STARTUP: logdone
   #+STARTUP: lognotedone

You can have local logging settings for a subtree by setting the LOGGING
property to one or more of these keywords.
```